# Change wordpress search results from post to product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm building a custom search page for my new site to include custom sections for both blog posts and product, but as a "bandaid" solution for the present, I want to  just return the search results for products and not posts.

I'm using Wordpress `v - 4.9.8` and using a Divi Child Theme (Divi Parent Theme `v - 3.17.6`)

I'm currently trying to hook into `pre_get_posts` with the following code in `functions.php`, but it's still only returning the "posts" results and not as products:

```
// LIMIT SEARCH TO POSTS OR PRODUCTS ONLY

add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter', 9);

function SearchFilter($query) {
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search ) {
$query->set('post_type', 'product'); 
}
return $query;
}
```

[Original Code Doc](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-custom-search-bar-headerfooter/)

Any ideas on how to make this work? I am thinking maybe making my own `search.php` page might work instead? I feel like something simple in `functions.php` would work better though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to follow below process to search by `products`

**Step - 1**

Search form for Custom Post Type: `Products`

---> Add Below code where you are representing your search form

```
    <div>   
    <h3>Search Products</h3>
    <form role="search" action="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>" method="get" id="searchform">
    <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search Products"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="products" /> <!-- // hidden 'products' value -->
    <input type="submit" alt="Search" value="Search" />
  </form>
 </div>
```

**Step - 2**

----> Add below code in your active themes `function.php`

```
function template_chooser($template)   
{    
  global $wp_query;   
  $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');   
  if( $wp_query->is_search && $post_type == 'products' )   
  {
    return locate_template('archive-search.php');  //  redirect to archive-search.php
  }   
  return $template;   
}
add_filter('template_include', 'template_chooser');
```

**Step- 3**

---> Create search result template for custom post type ( archive-search.php )

```
<?php
        /* Template Name: Custom Search */        
        get_header(); ?>             
        <div class="contentarea">
            <div id="content" class="content_right">  
                     <h3>Search Result for : <?php echo "$s"; ?> </h3>       
                     <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>    
                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="posts">        
                     <article>        
                    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>        
                    <p><?php the_exerpt(); ?></p>        
                    <p align="right"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read     More</a></p>    
                    <span class="post-meta"> Post By <?php the_author(); ?>    
                     | Date : <?php echo date('j F Y'); ?></span>    

                    </article><!-- #post -->    
                </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>




           </div><!-- content -->    
        </div><!-- contentarea -->   
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: yeah that didn't do anything, search bar still appeared the same way and searching for products still reveals things in blog search.